# Does the HttpClient API for WinRT perform auto decompression by default?

Tags: c#, http, windows-runtime

I'm trying to make a GET request to an HTTP server that supports content encoding, so basically I defined an HttpRequestMessage object added the appropriate request URI and added to the AcceptEncoding header gzip and then deflate, but for some reason the server is returning the content compressed, I've tested the same request with curl and it worked, does HttpClient perform auto decompression by default?

I've also checked the response headers for Content-Encoding, but it wasn't there, although when I did the same with curl the header was there.

Comment: It does, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter.automaticdecompression.aspx. Can you share the address that is not being decompressed?

Comment: Ohh thank you Kiewic, the problem is that response was coming already decompressed, so I thought I was doing something wrong.